# Exhaustive map over a union of typed objects

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, typescript2.0

I want TypeScript to enforce exhaustiveness when mapping over a union like this:

```
type Union = 
  { type: 'A', a: string } |
  { type: 'B', b: number }
```

The Union event handler:

```
const handle = (u: Union): string =>
  theMap[u.type](u);
```

It'd be great if here we could somehow get exhaustiveness check from TypeScript:

```
const theMap: { [a: string]: (u: Union) => string } = {
  A: ({a}: { type: 'A', a: string }) => 'this is a: ' + a,
  B: ({b}: { type: 'B', b: number }) => 'this is b: ' + b
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS2.8+

Since [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) were released, the manipulation needed to strongly type `theMap` has gotten a lot easier.  Here we will use [`Extract<U, X>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1461-L1464) to take a union type `U` and return only those constituents that are assignable to `X`:

```
type Union = { type: "A"; a: string } | { type: "B"; b: number };

const theMap: {
  [K in Union["type"]]: (u: Extract<Union, { type: K }>) => string
} = {
  A: ({ a }) => "this is a: " + a,
  B: ({ b }) => "this is b: " + b
};
```

Super simple!  Unfortunately, the compiler no longer allows you to call `theMap(u.type)(u)` since TS2.7 or so.  The function `theMap(u.type)` is *correlated* to the value `u`, but the compiler doesn't see that.  Instead it sees `theMap(u.type)` and `u` as independent union types and won't let you call one on the other without a type assertion:

```
const handle = (u: Union): string =>
  (theMap[u.type] as (v: Union) => string)(u); // need this assertion
```

or without manually walking through the possible union values:

```
const handle = (u: Union): string =>
  u.type === "A" ? theMap[u.type](u) : theMap[u.type](u); // redundant
```

I've generally been recommending people use assertions for this.

I've got an open issue about such [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581#issuecomment-500811519) but I don't know if there will ever be support for it.  Anyway, good luck again!

---

TS2.7 and below answer:

Given the type `Union` as defined, it's hard (or maybe impossible) to coax TypeScript into giving you a way to express both the exhaustiveness check (`theMap` contains exactly one handler for each constituent type of the union) and the soundness constraint (each handler in `theMap` is for a *specific* constituent type of the union).

However, it's possible to define `Union` in terms of a more general type, from which you can also express the above constraints.  Let's look at the more general type first:

```
type BaseTypes = {
  A: { a: string };
  B: { b: number };
}
```

Here, `BaseTypes` is a mapping from the `type` property of the original `Union` to the constituent types with `type` removed from them.  From this, `Union` is equivalent to `({type: 'A'} & BaseTypes['A']) | ({type: 'B'} & BaseTypes['B'])`.

Let's define some operations on type maps like `BaseTypes`:

```
type DiscriminatedType<M, K extends keyof M> = { type: K } & M[K];
type DiscriminatedTypes<M> = {[K in keyof M]: DiscriminatedType<M, K>};
type DiscriminatedUnion<M, V=DiscriminatedTypes<M>> = V[keyof V];
```

You can verify that `Union` is equivalent to `DiscriminatedUnion<BaseTypes>`:

```
type Union = DiscriminatedUnion<BaseTypes>
```

Additionally, it's helpful to define `NarrowedFromUnion`:

```
type NarrowedFromUnion<K extends Union['type']> = DiscriminatedType<BaseTypes, K>
```

which takes a key `K` and produces the constituent of the union with that `type`.  So `NarrowedFromUnion<'A'>` is one leg of the union and `NarrowedFromUnion<'B'>` is the other, and together they make up `Union`.

Now we can define the type of `theMap`:

```
const theMap: {[K in Union['type']]: (u: NarrowedFromUnion<K>) => string } = {
  A: ({ a }) => 'this is a: ' + a,
  B: ({ b }) => 'this is b: ' + b
};
```

It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) containing one property for each type in `Union`, which is a function from *that specific type* to a `string`.  This is exhaustive: if you leave out one of `A` or `B`, or put the `B` function on the `A` property, the compiler will complain.

That means we are able to omit the explicit annotation on `{a}` and `{b}`, since the type of `theMap` is now enforcing this constraint.  That's good, because the explicit annotation from your code was not really safe; you could have switched the annotations around and not been warned by the compiler, because all it knew was that the input was a `Union`.  (This kind of unsound type narrowing of function parameters is called [bivariance](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) and it's a mixed blessing in TypeScript.)

Now we should make `handle` be generic in the `type` of the `Union` parameter passed in:

**Update for TS2.7+**, the following function needs a type assertion due to lack of support for what I've been calling [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581#issuecomment-500811519).

```
const handle = <K extends Union['type']>(u: NarrowedFromUnion<K>): string =>
  (theMap[u.type] as (_: typeof u) => string)(u);
```

---

Okay, that was a lot.  Hope it helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey! Been a while. So I'm revisiting this as I need to update typescript on a project that was heavily relying on this pattern. However, the latest TS [doesn't work with this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-31f3av). Care to polish things up?

Comment: This pattern of `theMap[u.type](u)` has needed a type assertion (e.g., `(theMap[u.type] as (_: typeof u) => string)(u)`) since about TS2.7 or so.  It's a pain point due to the lack of support for what I've been calling ["correlated types"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Comment: Okay I updated the answer for newer versions of TS.

Comment: Always a joy educating myself with your answers. Waiting on your book on the advanced stuff.  Alright, so, in hopes of hiding this anomaly, I made an effort to abstract this whole thing into a function. I wanna say I succeeded, but I hope you’d be able to improve it. As such, I’m posting it as [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56762896/592641).