# Transform union into a map

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

Let's start with this given type:

```
type Union =
  { type: 'A', a: string } |
  { type: 'B', b: number }
```

I want us to end up here:

```
type MappedUnion = {
  A: { type: 'A', a: string }
  B: { type: 'B', b: number }
}
```

Here's some pseudo code:

```
type MappedUnion<item in Union> = {[ i: item['type'] ]: item}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exhaustive map over a union of typed objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641380/exhaustive-map-over-a-union-of-typed-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the following? Haven't tested exhaustively, but it seems to work.

```
type Union =
  { type: 'A', a: string } |
  { type: 'B', b: number }

type MappedUnion = {[P in Union['type']]: Union & {type: P}};

const v: MappedUnion = {
  'A': {type: 'A', a: "hello"},
  'B': {type: 'B', b: 3},
}
```

---

Sadly, doesn't quite work; If I do

```
type MappedUnionTarget = {
  A: { type: 'A', a: string }
  B: { type: 'B', b: number }
}

function cvt1(x: MappedUnion): MappedUnionTarget {
  return x;
}
```

then I get `Type '({ type: "A"; a: string; } & { type: "A"; }) | ({ type: "B"; b: number; } & { type: "A"; })' is not assignable to type '{ type: "A"; a: string; }'.` I thought typescript would be able to conclude that `({ type: "B"; b: number; } & { type: "A"; })` was the same as `never`.

---

If you're willing to use Typescript 2.8 (which at the time of writing is unreleased and available if you `git pull` from the TypeScript repo, and which has support for the conditional operator `? :` at the type level) then it seems you can do

```
type FilterType<T, K> = (T extends { type: K } ? T : never);

type MappedUnion = {[P in Union['type']]: FilterType<Union, P>};
```

because `FilterType<T, K>` is the thing that I had hoped `T & {type: K}` to behave like.

Comment: thanx for the effort, mate

Comment: Ah, I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641380/exhaustive-map-over-a-union-of-typed-objects and I see that their `NarrowedFromUnion` plays the same role as `FilterType` here. I think if you're not interested in using bleeding-edge typescript, their answer makes a lot of sense, but I think it's cool how much power conditional types give you if you're stuck with a union type defined by a library that you can't change.

Comment: I want us to be typescript friends