# Make a nicely typed generic event-to-handler assigner function

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, typescript-generics

This is a continuation of [this exploration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653607/592641) that figures out a reusable mechanism that lets us assign the incoming event(message) to the appropriate event handler and be completely type-reliant along the way. Here's what we wanna make reusable:

```js
const handleEvent = 
  <EventKind extends keyof EventsMap>
  (e: Event<EventKind>): Promise<void> => {
  const kind: EventKind = e.kind;
  const handler = <(e: CrmEvent<EventKind>) => Promise<void>>handlers[kind]; // Notice the seemingly unnecessary assertion. This is the reason we are making this function generic.
  return handler(e);
};
```

I want us to ideally end up here:

```
const handleEvent = eventAssigner<CrmEventsMap>(handlers, 'kind');
```

---

It all starts with a map that associates the events discriminator to the event body:

```js
interface CrmEventsMap {
  event1: { attr1: string,  attr2: number }
  event2: { attr3: boolean, attr4: string }
}
```

From which, we can create the complete Event type (one that includes the discriminator):

```js
type CrmEvent<K extends keyof CrmEventsMap> = { kind: K } & EventsMap[K]
```

We now have everything we need to declare the handlers map:

```js
const handlers: { [K in keyof CrmEventsMap]: (e: CrmEvent<K>) => Promise<void> } = {
  event1: ({attr1, attr2}) => Promise.resolve(),
  event2: ({attr3, attr4}) => Promise.resolve(),
};
```

Which brings us back to `handleEvent`. The type assertion in the body seems like a reason enough to try and make the function generic.

Here's an attempt:

```js
const eventAssigner =
  <EventMap extends {},
    EventKind extends keyof EventMap,
    KindField extends string>
  (
    handlers: { [k in keyof EventMap]: (e: EventType<EventMap, k, KindField>) => any },
    kindField: KindField
  ) =>
    (e: EventType<EventMap, EventKind, KindField>):
      ReturnType<(typeof handlers)[EventKind]> => {
      const kind = e[kindField];
      const handler = <(e: EventType<EventMap, EventKind, KindField>) => ReturnType<(typeof handlers)[EventKind]>>handlers[kind];
      return handler(e);
    };

type EventType<EventMap extends {}, Kind extends keyof EventMap, KindField extends string> =
  { [k in KindField]: Kind } & EventMap[Kind]
```

It's quite convoluted, even in it's usage. But then, just by fixing-in the events discriminator field to `'kind'`, we dramatically simplify things:

```
const eventAssigner =
  <EventMap extends {},
    EventKind extends keyof EventMap>
  (handlers: { [k in keyof EventMap]: (e: EventType<EventMap, k>) => any }) =>
    (e: EventType<EventMap, EventKind>):
      ReturnType<(typeof handlers)[EventKind]> =>
      handlers[e.kind](e);

type EventType<EventMap extends {}, Kind extends keyof EventMap> = { kind: Kind } & EventMap[Kind]
```

What's especially interesting in this one is that for some reason I'm not able to explain, we don't need the type assertion.

Still, for any of these two functions to work, they need to be provided the concrete type arguments, which means wrapping them in another function:

```
const handleEvent = 
  <E extends CrmEventKind>
  (e: CrmEvent<E>): ReturnType<(typeof handlers)[E]> => 
    eventAssigner<CrmEventMap, E>(handlers)(e);
```

So in short, how much closer to the ideal implementation do you think we can get?

[Here's a playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-uk0zIyFlHLkIDi3Mx8WBy-ZAWSKUpKyIzBZU-VUiw6X4emA2KspX4AvJuy8+5YOxI0oXwVpFDOyHpDMYF1ZHnZuJj6+5VyhvPTNw4cs4IG5FWDzwUHQ9bD38HulyXvs1czAiyg35Zm23BLsCWyPhC-7FtCcJLki4IosQQA)

Comment: Hmm, I find the question kind of hard to read. A complete copy of the current implementation would help. I tried copy-pasting the pieces of code to TS playground, but couldn't work it out.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen thanx for pointing it out. Added a playground, but also fixed a couple of mistakes in the question.

Comment: By improving the implementation further, do you mean shortening the definition of "handleEvent" and "eventAssigner", or improving the interface of calling "handleEvent" ?

Currently we need to do:
handleEvent({ kind: 'event1', attr1: 'hello', attr2: 0 })

I guess it would be logical to be able to omit the 'kind' property, if the event signatures are unique.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen `kind` is necessary as it is the only field that completely differentiates one event from another. My goal is to just "improve the interface" of calling `eventAssigner` to look as close as possible to: `eventAssigner<CrmEventsMap>(handlers, 'kind')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hitting myself in the head a few times to understand what's going on here, I've got something.

First I'd suggest loosening your type for `handlers` a bit so as not to *require* that the handler arguments feature the `"kind"` discriminant, like this:

```
interface CrmEventMap {
  event1: { attr1: string; attr2: number };
  event2: { attr3: boolean; attr4: string };
}

const handlers: {
  [K in keyof CrmEventMap]: (e: CrmEventMap[K]) => Promise<void>
} = {
  event1: ({ attr1, attr2 }) => Promise.resolve(),
  event2: ({ attr3, attr4 }) => Promise.resolve()
};
```

So you don't need `CrmEvent<K>` at all here.  Your eventual `handleEvent` implementation will need to use a discriminant to tell how to dispatch events, but the `handlers` above doesn't care: each function will only operate on an event that has already been appropriately dispatched.  You can keep the above stuff the same as you had it if you want, but it seems unnecessary to me.

Now for the implementation of `eventAssigner`:

```
const eventAssigner = <
  M extends Record<keyof M, (e: any) => any>,
  D extends keyof any
>(
  handlers: M,
  discriminant: D
) => <K extends keyof M>(
  event: Record<D, K> & (Parameters<M[K]>[0])
): ReturnType<M[K]> => handlers[event[discriminant]](event);
```

So, `eventAssigner` is a curried generic function.  It is generic in `M`, the type of `handlers` (which you have as the variable `handlers`) which must be an object holding one-argument function properties, and `D`, the type of `discriminant` (which you have as the string `"kind"`) which must be a valid key type.  It then returns another function which is generic in `K`, intended to be one of the keys of `M`.  Its `event` parameter is of type `Record<D, K> & (Parameters<M[K]>[0])` which basically means it must be the same type argument as the `K`-keyed property of `M`, as well as an object with a discriminant key `D` and value `K`.  This is the analog of your `CrmEvent<K>` type.

And it returns `ReturnType<M[K]>`.  This implementation doesn't need a type assertion only because the constraint on `M` has each handler function extend `(e: any)=>any`.  So when the compiler examines `handlers[event[discriminant]]` it sees a function that must be assignable to `(e: any)=>any`, and you can basically call it on any argument and return any type.  So it would happily let you return `handlers[event[discriminant]]("whoopsie") + 15`.  So you need to be careful here.  You could dispense with `any` and use something like `(e: never)=>unknown` which would be safer but then you'd have to use a type assertion.  It's up to you.

Anyway here's how you use it:

```
const handleEvent = eventAssigner(handlers, "kind");
```

Note that you are just using generic type inference and don't have to specify anything like `<CrmEventsMap>` in there.  In my opinion using type inference is more 
"ideal" than manually specifying things.  If you want to specify something here it would have to be `eventAssigner<typeof handlers, "kind">(handlers, "kind")`, which is silly.

And making sure that it behaves as you expect:

```
const event1Response = handleEvent({ kind: "event1", attr1: "a", attr2: 3 }); // Promise<void>
const event2Response = handleEvent({ kind: "event2", attr3: true, attr4: "b" }); // Promise<void>
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps. Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQLYFEBuFwCycADsgN4BQyyEe4AjAFznJxhhRPIDOHoA5gG5W7KACZmIAK4YARtGQBfQVRp0wElmw4BmZrID2BgDYQ4IYdqgAWZrygClKxRQoIDIXsgAW5gCamUNzMlNQA2gDSyKDIANYQAJ4GMGiYuPhgRMQAuswAFBDM6NjqWZHZAJTIALwAfMgAClAGGMDcEAA8OAbAfrUUijXkqrQZXHlkIhz0ADRT4kpVdY3Nre0AdFAQ3CZ4eRUzI+qaE-M6c1bWizX1TS1tEJvbuxD7AypuHl6j4ACC3NxgPwQApqsgOqoCDQAB6QEB+bjIABKEHcUD8HXiSRSBDmBWY5gSS3qhNqh2oABEYXCEXFEslWCAEhRanlVL54YFgshcao-G0EA5WiBzGBmBSKMTwVEILD8LSsQyCKyjhlmCi0RiKXMIvUAGTIPINOBQOAYCCQIIdAjlWphAAMlUl6otUigIAAKgliJ0bRFsvVlhyAtBuGEfmAwvzuILgMLRdlsgV1BUPu5PGAfP5TOlwEMI-9AcDoHlg1y5gAiWKgPwV1OfDNqMYo7jEL4oMFliC5sCnavw5gViP0CsXURcCuj+aae2LYQAennK3u7S6PT6De+xxbbc8HaznO76j7NcHEbEU6semQHCkEDHHFsyEnc+Qi+Xa063V6-SAA)

Comment: It’s so beautiful, got tears in my eyes. I didn’t event hope that it’d be possible to leave out the event map type. Thank you for going the extra mile!

Comment: Please if possible, recommend some literature that would help me put all these type-related problems into my deep intuition. I wanna write types like I write code.

Either that, or I'll need to keep bothering you :} In meantime, just start your own book already! (I already tried picking up a couple of, but they quickly go into typing up classes, which is when I fall asleep)

Comment: I don't know if I have any one thing to recommend.  I started with the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) (and there's a newer version in development [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/outline/)), but after that I've spent a lot of time reading through the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc).

Comment: I managed to represent a usecase from my app in which `eventAssigner` doesn't accept the event. [Here's the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-issue?embed=1&file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1&hideNavigation=1&view=editor). Please find the issue in the `proxyEventAssigner` function. (Couldn't use Playground because of the url size)

Comment: I don't know if I'll be able to get to this or come up with a better answer other than "use a type assertion", so you might want to ask a new question if you want a greater chance of getting eyes on this.

Comment: Thanx, [here it goes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57925619/592641). I think understanding where is the difference between the types is a good start for me.